# NTFS formatted HDDs doesn't show in Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ntfs, format

I formatted two HDDs in win11 with NTFS and then I moved those to a server with Ubuntu server.

Now the os doesn't find those new HDDs. What did I do wrong. I am a beginner with the linux environment. Those HDDs have power in server. BIOS doesn't find those HDDs.

Comment: "BIOS doesn't find those HDDs."  that is not an Ubuntu problem... if `fdisk` does not list them or the BIOS does not see internal harddisks it is a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

if ...
`$ lsblk -ape7 -o +FSTYPE,MODEL,PARTLABEL,LABEL`
... shows at least basic info of your HDD's, then...

I would *GUESS* you actually mean
that your Ubuntu OS doesn't (allow to) **mount** NTFS formatted disks;
then you need to find and install a NTFS filesystem.

Try:
`$ sudo apt install ntfs-3g`
... and see what difference it makes.

Comment: I've understood that it's already in ubuntu server origally inside.

Comment: `$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/device` and it will show up in `/media/$USER/`

Comment: I will test those things.

Comment: Corrected: To verify: `$ dpkg -l | grep -i ntfs` should have `ii` in the leftmost column for e.g. `ntfs-3g`. If that is present AND lsblk shows your disks and partitions, all you have to do is MOUNT them.

Comment: ntfs-3g on jo ja udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/device -komento sanoo että error looking up object for device /dev/device. /media/$user -komento sanoo että: -bash: /media/: is a directory. Viimeisintä komentoa en ole ajanut.

Comment: The language here is english only, please keep it that way. Now `/dev/device` (example) is to be replaced by the suitable left column content from lsblk output. The last command tells whether you actually have any ntfs things installed.